# Create HTTP request queue on apache2, Ubuntu 12.04 and PHP

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I am creating a web application which will support more than 2000 users.
But 2000 concurrent connection will create problem in apache.
So, I googled and found a way that we can create HTTP request queue on server and handle them one by one. 
But how should I achieve it using apache and PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using NGINX or another event-driven server, as it will do what you're wanting without re-creating the wheel by building an HTTP request queue.  Of course, if you really want to scale properly, you may think about a load balancer with more than one web server behind it.  2000 concurrent connections is quite large, and really isn't necessary for 2000 users, as not all users will be sending requests simultaneously.   The "connection" only last as long as it takes to serve up a page.

You can also use Apache Benchmark  (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) to do some quick, preliminary load testing.  I believe you'll find that you don't need near the resources you think you do.

Comment: I have tried ngnix and apache both. What I did was, I used Jmeter to create 500 HTTP  request for accessing JSON data from Server. in such a case apache failed after 200 requests and nginx failed after 110 request.

Comment: Failed, meaning the server locked up?  Or, did the responses time out?

Comment: 504 Gateway timed out on Nginx

Comment: Was the JSON data static or being served by PHP and a database call?

Comment: Yea.. I'm not sure.  Neither of those servers should have problems with that load.  It makes me wonder if the file is locking or something, preventing the script from reading it.  Regardless, to your original point, if you have 2000 users on your site, that doesn't necessarily equal 2000 concurrent connections.

Comment: I have tested on apache also, during failure the response was connection refused.